# AWS adding load balancer and autoscaling to existing https instance using let's encrypt

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb, lets-encrypt

I have an existing EC2 instance running Apache2 where I set https on, using let's encrypt service. Now I'd like to create an autoscaling group (with 1 to 3 of these instances) and a load balancer and I'd like to keep my https certificate.

Which is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the SSL certificate is going to be installed on each EC2 instance, then you can just setup port 443 on the load balancer as a TCP listener, and it will pass the traffic on port 443 directly to the instance, where the SSL certificate will be served.

Note that this is going to require Let's Encrypt be working on each instance that gets created. It will really be easier for you to get a new (free) certificate via the AWS ACM service, and install that on the load balancer.

Comment: well i would like to keep an end to end https connection, on the autoscaling group I will add just AMI of my actual instance so every instance will have the let's encrypt certificate working on it... 
wich is the difference using the amazon certificate?

Comment: You wouldn't have end-to-end encryption with the AWS certificate, but you would only have one certificate installation location to deal with. SSL encryption would be offloaded from your instances, which would reduce server CPU usage some, and the certificate wouldn't expire as often. However if you want encryption all the way to the instances then just use Let's Encrypt like you plan to. Although, a proper VPC configuration makes encryption between the ELB and EC2 instances completely unnecessary unless you have some sort of regulatory reason (like PCI or HIPAA) which requires it.

Comment: Everytime I try to select secure protocol (tcp or https) in the listener list, aws tells me I need a certificate... 

I'm trying to figure out how to set up the ELB correctly to use my existing instance without the need of another certificate...

Comment: Don't select HTTPS. Don't select SSL. Don't select "Secure TCP". Just select **TCP**